# PHP. Pass variable by reference vs string. How to works with these two different arguments?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I'm writing my own debug functions and I need some help to fix the code below.

I'm trying to print a variable and its name, the file where the variable and the function was declared and the line of the function call. The first part I did, the variable, the variable name, the file and the line is printed correctly.
At the code, *a($variable)* works good.

The problem is I'd like this function accepts a string too, out of a variable. But PHP returns with a fatal error (*PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in ...*). At the code, *a('text out')*.

So, how can I fix this code to accept a variable or a string correctly?

**code (edited):**

```
function a(&$var){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $call = array_shift($backtrace);

    $line = $call['line'];
    $file = $call['file'];

    echo name($var)."<br>".$var."<br>".$line."<br>".$file;
}

$variable='text in';
a($variable);
a('text out');
```

I need pass the variable by reference to use this function below (the function get the variable name correctly, works with arrays too):

```
function name(&$var, $scope=false, $prefix='unique', $suffix='value'){
   if($scope) $vals = $scope;
   else      $vals = $GLOBALS;
   $old = $var;
   $var = $new = $prefix.rand().$suffix;
   $vname = FALSE;
   foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
      if($val === $new) $vname = $key;
   }
   $var = $old;
   return $vname;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing by reference?

Comment: Because I need this to get the name of the var correctly. Another function of mine.

Comment: I agree with the others, but from a pure solution standpoint, why not pass in a variable that references a string instead of a string literal?

Comment: Yes. I could do this. But because this function is to use at the debug process I would like write the less as possible, like *a($test)* and *a('else')*.

Comment: I suspect you can't "fix" this.  It seems to be working very much as designed.  The PHP docs are very specific about references relating to variables, and not constants.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is currently implementing [`pass by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) is perfect by design, but also by design cannot be changed to have two `a()` methods - one accepting a variable by reference and the other as a string-literal.

If the desire to pass a string literal instead of assigning it to a variable first is really needed, I would suggest creating a second convenience method named `a_str()` that actually accepts a string-literal instead of a variable by reference. This method's sole-purpose would be to relay the variable(s) to the original `a()` method - thereby declaring a variable to pass by reference.

```
function a_str($var) {
    a($var);
}
```

The only thing to remember is, use `a($variable);` when passing by reference and `a_str('some text');` when not.

Here is the same convenience-method for your `name()` function:

```
function name_str($var, $scope=false, $prefix='unique', $suffix='value'){
    return name($var, $scope, $prefix, $suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you are asking without writing an additional function like @newfurniturey suggests is plain and simply opening and parsing the file where your function was called as text (e.g. with `fopen`), using the data from `debug_backtrace`. This will be expensive in terms of performance, but it might be ok if used only for debugging purposes; and using this method you will no longer need a reference in your function, which means you can freely accept a literal as the parameter.